# Double tapping functionalities in Google Map and Paint tool

Tags: android, google-maps, drawing, gesture

I have a made an App(for practices only) that can draw above the Google Map using a Paint tool. Now when i press the draw button the map will be lock(disabling the gesture) in its desired place. Now i wanted to Enable again by double tapping the canvas the reason is, when i wanted to extend my drawing and again by double tapping it will be lock and continue my drawing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of [Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events) you can look at but I think double-tapping will be a bit difficult (I think you'll have to implement it thru `onMapClick`). But basically if you're going to that route, you'll just need a flag that triggers the enable/disable of gestures inside of it.

Comment: Sir I'm still looking for some alternatives. I'm looking for some suggestions.